# REST System - but there is no need for Delete or Put -> Still REST?

Tags: node.js, rest, client

i searched the Web for the definition of Restful systems but im still confused.

I have a nodejs-Server where i use the HTTP-methods GET for getting a resource and post for uploading a resource. And i use JSON as a data format.

But the clients are not allowed to delete or change a ressource, so there is no need for Delete or Put.

So is this still considered as a RESTful system or is it only based on it but no 'real' RESTful system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restful service does not requires to use all types of http request. But there are some best practices for selecting http method type (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE) for each request.
These are the main features of the rest:

- it is based on http request/response
- you have no restrictions in data format, you can use JSON, XML, Atom, ...
- it is stateless

Comment: You're right what you described is a HTTP protocol it self. The REST is nothing more or less than using the HTTP in proper way to manipulate with data resources.